# What is the quotient of two quantum operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, hilbert-space, singularities

It's probably useful to explain the context, which led me to this question. We were asked the following question:

By writing ${L}^2 = \sum_{ijklm}\epsilon_{ijk}{x}_j{p}_k\epsilon_{ilm}{x}_l{p}_m$ show that: $$p^2 = \frac{L^2}{r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}\left\{(\textbf{r}\cdot \textbf{p})^2-i\hbar(\textbf{r}\cdot \textbf{p})\right\}$$

I got up to this point: $${L}^2 = {\textbf{r}}^2{\textbf{p}}^2-\left(\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{p}\right)^2+i\hbar\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{p}$$

However now my question is, am I allowed to just divide by $\textbf{r}^2$ and if yes what is the interpretation of a division of two quantum operators? After all $L,\textbf{r},\textbf{p}$ are all quantum operators so I'm quite worried about just applying "normal" Algebra rules and callying it a day.

Comment: You should be able to show that $L^2$ commutes with $r^2$ --it is a function of just θ and φ, so it does not matter if you multiply by the inverse on the left or the right. As far as these two operators are concerned, they are "numbers to each other".

Comment: @Cosmas it commutes with the squared L, but does it commute with $p^2$? What about the other two terms? The presence of an imaginary term is a smoking-gun indicator that some terms don't commute, so any order switching should be done very carefully.

Comment: @Emilio I strongly suspect the entire point of the exercise is to help the OP appreciate $[L^2,r]=0$ even though commutativity of individual pieces fails... the sort of thing that happens with pieces of the Hamiltonian, too... $r^2$ can divide the whole $L^2$ on the left or the right. But any expectation it could/should divide individual pieces is misplaced.

Comment: @CosmasZachos But it *is* multiplying the individual pieces ─ specifically, the $p^2$ of the LHS of the final result, which doesn't commute with $r^2$ if I didn't screw up my back-of-the-envelope commutators.

Comment: @Emilio Well,   $L^2/r^2= r^2 p^2 1/r^2 + \{...\} 1/r^2$ is also correct, but egregiously silly... The only term you need not be order-conscious with is the l.h.side, of course...

Comment: @EmilioPisanty You don't need to do any calculation to see that $p^2$ and $r^2$ don't commute. If they did, then the 3D harmonic oscillator would be effectively classical; its ground state would individually minimize both the kinetic and potential terms, and there would be no zero-point energy. But since the 3D HO is just the sum of three decoupled 1D HOs, this clearly isn't the case.

Comment: @tparker I think both you and Cosmas are missing the point. I was exclusively addressing the claim that the operators involved are just  "numbers to each other" - this might be true for some combinations, but not for all the relevant ones here. I don't see what further discussion of minutiae on this thread will accomplish beyond just confusing 1MegaMan1.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I didn't actually read any of the thread. I just noticed that you mentioned calculating "back-of-the-envelope commutators" to check whether $x^2$ and $p^2$ commute, and thought I'd share a nice quick trick for seeing that they don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, it's a subtle issue. You can't just divide two non-commuting operators - you need to specify whether you're left-multiplying or right-multiplying the numerator by the reciprocal of the denominator. I would avoid ever using "division" notation and only multiply operators and their reciprocals, for clarity. You can left-multiply your operator expression by $\left({\bf r}^2 \right)^{-1}$ to get one particular quantization of the final result that you're supposed to show.

Strictly speaking, in $d$ spatial dimensions the domain of the operator $r^{-2}$ is the subset of the Hilbert space $L^2 \left( \mathbb{R}^d \right)$ which $r^{-2}$ takes to $L^2 \left( \mathbb{R}^d \right)$, i.e. the set of square-integrable functions $\psi({\bf r})$ such that
$$\left \langle \psi \middle| \left(r^{-2} \right)^\dagger r^{-2} \middle| \psi \right \rangle = \int d^dx\ \frac{|\psi({\bf r})|^2}{r^4} = \int d\Omega \int r^{d-1} dr \frac{|\psi(r, \Omega)|^2}{r^4}$$
is finite. This is the set of functions $\psi({\bf r})$ that go to zero at the origin at least as fast as $r^p$ for some power $p > 4 - d$. In three spatial dimensions, this means that $\psi({\bf r})$ must go to zero faster than $r$ near the origin.

Comment: The origin of what? The domain of that function is (a subspace of) Hilbert space.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The operator is defined for wavefunctions that vanish sufficiently quickly near the origin. Edited to clarify.

Comment: So you're saying that in order to keep everything clear and non-confusing I should avoid writing $\frac{A}{r^2}$ as this is ambiguous and could either mean $\left(r^2\right)^{-1}A$ or $A\left(r^2\right)^{-1}$, which don't necessarily have to be the same.

However there's one more thing which I'm a bit confused about, why is it true that in position representation the inverse of $r^2$, $\left(r^2\right)^{-1}$, is simply $\frac{1}{r^2}$? What would for example then be the inverse of $p^2$, $\left(p^2\right)^{-1}$, in position representation?

Comment: This is an excellent answer, of course. I'd be a bit 'softer' on the notation, though: I don't find $\frac{1}{r^2}$ problematic (with a unit numerator!), nor do I have a problem with $\frac{A}{B}$ when it's obvious that $[A,B]=0$. On the other hand, something as complicated as $A=(\textbf{r}\cdot \textbf{p})^2-i\hbar(\textbf{r}\cdot \textbf{p})$ should never really be on a numerator, unless it's been made explicitly and at good lengths clear that it commutes with the numerator.

Comment: @1MegaMan1 Yeah, it can be a bit confusing to distinguish between the multiplicative inverse (reciprocal) and the functional (e.g. matrix) inverse. It's easiest in the operator's eigenbasis, when the two notions are more or less the same (you just reciprocate each eigenvalue). That's why the operator inverse of $r^2$ is just $1/r^2$ in the position basis. Inverting $p^2$ in the position basis is trickier; it doesn't actually have a proper two-sided inverse, but it does have a right-inverse $1/(4 \pi \hbar^2 r)$ called the "Green's function" for the Laplacian operator.